# Event bubbling for parent of <a>, which returns false from onclick event listener

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-events, event-bubbling

I try to make a common solution for the following task: `onclick` event listener for element

```
<a href="#">Some text</a>
```

must return false. It can stop page scrolling after click.

```
$("a[href='#']").bind("click", function () { return false; });
```

It can stop scrolling but `return false` stop bubbling too! So, if I have the following code:

HTML

```
<div class="clickable">
   <a href="#">Text</a>
</div>
```

Javascript (JQuery)

```
$("a[href='#']").bind("click", function () { return false; });
$(".clickable").bind("click", function(){alert("It works!");})
```

and if I click on "Text", there is no alert.

Can I restore bubbling? Or, may be, there is any another common way to return false from `onclick` event listener of every such "a" tag? Or the only way is to add listener `function(){alert("It works!");}` on "a"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function's signature to accept the event args and use `preventDefault`:

```
$("a[href='#']").bind("click", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
$(".clickable").bind("click", function(){alert("It works!");})
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZEhV/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Some text</a>
```

Your jQuery-bound click functions should keep working.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mU2dq/1/

Answer (score 1):

To stop something from bubbling I always follow this:

```
$('myAnchor').live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    //or if you want to stop all handlers
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    //code here

    //for IE etc.
    return false;
});
```

Comment: He doesn't want to stop something bubbling, he wants to allow bubbling.

Comment: Stop propagation will prevent it from bubbling

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - Ah I misinterpreted the "stop bubbling too"